# Remove invalid values in Talend

Tags: java, talend

I have an excel input file with a date column, some of those dates are not correct and when executing my job, I got the following error

```
The cell format is not Date in ( Row. 128 and ColumnNum. 3 )
The cell format is not Date in ( Row. 172 and ColumnNum. 3 )
The cell format is not Date in ( Row. 315 and ColumnNum. 3 )
The cell format is not Date in ( Row. 406 and ColumnNum. 3 )
```

I would like then to filter these values so that I will avoid this kind of error
In fact, the rows where the date is not correct contains the value "-", that means that we don t know the correct date. It would be great if I can simply filter all the rows which have an incorrect date format.

I m thinking about a filter or an If condition, but as my input column is a date, I have some difficulties.

Any Help? Thanks :)

Comment: Can you post the code of the job?

Comment: there is nothing really interesting behind the code because I just put some components without really functions
`
 * [tFilterRow_8 end ] start
  */

 

 
 
 currentComponent="tFilterRow_8";

 
    globalMap.put("tFilterRow_8_NB_LINE", nb_line_tFilterRow_8);
    globalMap.put("tFilterRow_8_NB_LINE_OK", nb_line_ok_tFilterRow_8);
    globalMap.put("tFilterRow_8_NB_LINE_REJECT", nb_line_reject_tFilterRow_8);
    

 

ok_Hash.put("tFilterRow_8", true);
end_Hash.put("tFilterRow_8", System.currentTimeMillis());




/**
 * [tFilterRow_8 end ] stop
 */`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a first step where you retrieve your Date field from excel as a String : this way you won't get any error. Then with a tFilterRow, you can exclude rows where date is "-". Then you convert in a tMap your string to a Date using TalendDate.parseDate method.